# Issue with placing variable with string in ASP/Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, variables, visual-studio-2012

First off, forgive me for I know very little about MS Visual Studio & ASP, but my issue is that I can not seem to figure out the syntax for placing a variable within a string in the following ASP code....

```
    description = viewCat[0]["description"].ToString();

metaHTML = @"
    <title></title>
    <meta name='description' content='" + description + "' />
";
```

Question I'm looking for is what is the correct way of placing the variable "description" within the string??

Comment: Can you describe what's going wrong with the code you're using?

Answer (score 1):

To create a string from a variable, you can use String.Format:

```
string description = "something";
string formattedStr = String.Format("Some string and {0}",description);
```

In your case:

```
description = viewCat[0]["description"].ToString();
metaHTML = String.Format("<title></title><meta name='description' content='{0}'/>", description);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your assignment of `metaHTML` comprises three strings - two literals and the variable `description`. Only the *first* literal is a multiline string (you prefix it with `@`). The second string is not: the characters `"' />` are an unterminated string, and aren't correlated with the characters on the next line.

What you want to do is this - note the extra `@`:

```
metaHTML = @"
    <title></title>
    <meta name='description' content='" + description + @"' />
";
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much, Dan... this helps me out a lot!

Answer (score 0):

What is the error that you get since this is a nice way of doing the stuff that you're talking about.

```
@"<title></title>
<meta name='description' content='" + description + "' />";
```

The only thing that you *must* worry about is any un escapted `"` inside the string. On the first occurance this string would break the string. Otherwise it would work.

#### Red squiggly lines in VS

In the Visual Studio the Red Squiggly lines are due to the error in the String length. In ASP.NET and C# to create multiline Strings you use `@` before the string to make it multiline. Like the first line of your String value.

Otherwise each string is single line and you cannot start a new line in it like you're doing right now. So either use this

```
<meta name='description' content='" + description + "' />";
```

... or else use this

```
<!-- note the @ in the string -->
<meta name='description' content='" + description + @"' />
";
```

The better function is to use the first code I provided, because it ends the line where it must be ended. Try it, it would remove the red lines.

Comment: Well, It seems when I place that variable as it is, Visual Studio indicates that something might be wrong by placing "squiggly" lines under each character after the "+ description +" variable.... make sense?

Comment: Yes it does. Wait let me write it out.

Comment: @GreggMoore, have a look now. It explains those lines.